# Angular: Get prefetch factory function parameters from a file

Tags: angular

In my application, before loading the main page, I prefetch some data from a file and from some APIs to use later. For this, I use a factory function like this one:

```
export function referenceRateProviderFactory(provider: FetchReferenceService) {
  return () =>
    provider.fetchReferenceRate('www.google.com', 'user/password');
}
```

Where the link and the user/password pair are passed as strings in that function.

I also have a factory like this one

```
export function configDataProvideFactory(provider: ConfigService) {
  return () => provider.fetchConfig();
}
```

That takes data from a file which is stored in the src folder.

This is how I declare my prefetch in app.module.ts, in providers:

```
{ provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: configDataProvideFactory, deps: [ConfigService], multi: true }
{ provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: referenceRateProviderFactory, deps: [FetchReferenceService], multi: true }
```

My question is, since I know that I have the file locally, and I know that the file contains in some keys the URL 'www.google.com' and the 'user/password' pair, and I have that ConfigService that stores all the file data, can I somehow instead of passing the URL and the user/password as strings for the fetchReferenceRate(), use what it is in the ConfigService, or use some other way to get those parameters from the file itself?

All of those functions posted above are stored in `app.modules.ts`.

Comment: In my opinion, it's better to keep the info in the environment variable rather than a file.

Comment: I didn't know about the environment variable, so I was using a service to get the same kind of data I would store in one. I moved the keys from the file to the environment and I can use it in my app.module. Thank you for the answer :)